# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" when adding service reference on WIndows 10

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I made application which use service at this address: https://webapp2.rzzo.rs/rzzo/RzzoService?wsdl ,before 3 years, and everything works fine. But now on windows 10 it doesn't work. And on earlier version on windows os it works.
I try to make a new application from beginning, and when i try to add service reference in Visual Studio 2013 to service on above address, it says:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://webapp2.rzzo.rs/rzzo/RzzoService?wsdl'. Could not establish
>   secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'webapp2.rzzo.rs'.

I try same procedure on another computer, but now with Windows 7, and there in no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Algorithm in order to make it work. Using Windows Registry Editor (**regedit**):

1. Create new key **Diffie-Hellman**, at location:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms

2. Create new DWORD value named **Enabled** and set it to 1

Restart of machine is not necessary.

Regards,
Dejan

[RegEdit state after applied changes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqz1k.png)