# VS 2013/Windows 10: Adding/Updating Service Reference getting message Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl

I have a project originally developed in VS2010 .NET 4.  I need to upgrade it to use TLS 1.2 so I have copied it to my Windows 10 machine running VS1013.  I set the framework to 4.5.2 and recompile with no issues.

When I try to Update the Service Reference, I receive the “Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel” error.  I am able to see the wsdl contents in a browser and I have installed the certificate under Trusted Authority.

If I try to add a New Service Reference in this, and a different project, I get the same error message.

I read this question [“Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel” when adding service reference on WIndows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988214/could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-when-adding-service-reference-on-windo) but that did not solve the problem though I have not restarted my machine as the answer said I didn't need to.

I am stuck trying to figure out where the actual issue lies.

TLS 1.2 is enabled in IE Internet Settings.

Thank you

Comment: You need to upgrade to .NET 4.6 to make this work or force .NET via registry as mentioned here [Update .NET web service to use TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45382254/205233)

Comment: @Filburt This is what confuses me. I  don't understand why I need to upgrade to 4.6 in order to ADD a reference.  I can understand doing this when running the application, but the very act of adding or updating needs the newer framework?

Comment: Just a vague guess but VS seems to employ the projects .NET version to configure and create the service reference.

Comment: If you want to get to the bottom of this you could use ProcMon to find out which version of SvcUtil.exe Visual Studio calls depending on the selected .NET framework.

Comment: I ended up installing VS 2017 Community edition and that solved my problem.  I opened the VS 2013 project in 2017, recompiled just to make sure and then Updated the Reference and did not receive the error message.  The framework was left at 4.5.2 so I don't think that was the real issue, @Filburt but I do appreciate all the suggestions.  I also noticed that Windows 10  has framework 4.7 installed, that is what shows when I checked the Add or Remove Windows Features.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use VS2013, then the trick is to view the WSDL in a browser i.e.
visit https://www.somesite.com/api.asmx?wsdl

Then save the WSDL to disk.

In VS2013, Right click on the project and select "Add Service Reference..."
In the Address: box, enter the physical path (C:\downloads..) of the downloaded/Modified WSDL. Then press Go.

Or update to a later version of Visual Studio.